# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating this.props.navigation.navigate) in react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I have just started with React Native. Here is the code

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Splash from "./screens/splash";
import Home from "./screens/home";
import Card from "./screens/card";

export const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: 'Profile',
    },
  },
  Card: {
    screen: Card,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
});

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { showSplash: true };

    // after 1200ms change showSplash property for spalsh screen
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(previousState => {
        return { showSplash: false };
      });
    }, 1200);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.showSplash) {
      return (<Splash />);
    } else {
      return (<RootNavigator />);
    }
  }
}
```

In the **home.js** I am using card component directly like this

```
<ScrollView>
{
  this.state.cards.map((data, index) => {
    return (
      <Card key={data.id} cardData={data} />
    );
  })
}
```

and here is the **card.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';

export default class Card extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={{ flex: 0.30 }}>
                    <Image source={{ uri: this.props.cardData.imgUrl }} style={{ height: 100 }} />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 0.70, backgroundColor: 'steelblue' }}>
                    <Text >{this.props.cardData.name}</Text>
                    <Text >{this.props.cardData.imgUrl}</Text>
                    <Button
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', {})}
                        title="Profile"
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Now if I use

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
```

in the **profile.js** it works but in case of **card.js** it is showing

```
TypeError : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')
```

This question is asked many times and tried all the solutions provided by the answers, but none of the answers helped.

What could be this possible issue? Is this because I am using `<Card>` in the `Home` component

Comment: I don't see you setting `navigation` prop for Card component. How do you define it for profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, `Card` component in your `home.js` screen is component in `card.js`.

Because you are using `Card` component directly in home.js (not navigating to it with react-navigation), navigation prop is not being injected. If you want your current code to work, you should pass navigation prop to your card component from profile.js

```
const { navigation } = this.props;
...
<ScrollView>
{
  this.state.cards.map((data, index) => {
    return (
      <Card navigation={navigation} key={data.id} cardData={data} />
    );
  })
}
</ScrollView>
```

Most probably, you are opening your profile.js screen with `this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')`, so it is working fine there.

Comment: Though I am not navigating the card component through navigation but I have defined the same in stack navigator. Is not there any other way ?